# Quasi-unipotent monodromy for variation of Landau-Ginzburg cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, d-modules, monodromy

A pair, $(X,f)$, consisting of a smooth variety and a global function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^{1}$ is called a *Landau-Ginzburg model*, LG-model for short. The LG-cohomology of the pair, dentoed $H(X,f)$, is defined to be the hypercohomology of the complex $(\Omega^{*}_{X},d+df)$, equivalently the de Rham cohomology of the $D_{X}$-module $\mathcal{O} _{X}e^{f}$.

I´m interested in the variation of the LG-model cohomology over a base, which for simplicity I´ll take to be a small complex analytic punctured disc $\Delta^{*}_{z}$. So let´s consider the $D_{X}$-module which is obtained as $D$-module pushforward of the $D_{X\times\Delta^{*}_{\hbar}}$-module $\mathcal{O}e^{\frac{f}{z}}$, along the projection to $X$. We obtain thus a monodromy representation of $\mathbb{Z}\cong\pi_{1}(\Delta_{z}^{*})$ on the general fibre, a (graded) vector space isomorphic to $H(X,f)$.

**My question** is when I should expect this monodromy to be quasi-unipotent, that is to say when I should expect all the eigenvalues of the monodromy to be roots of unity. There is deep and somewhat forbidding modern theory of exponential mixed Hodge structures, due to Sabbah, Mochizuki and others, which perhaps contains an answer but I am unable to find it.

*Remark*. I believe that in simple cases the monodromy is indeed quasi-unipotent, for example I did the computation for $X=\mathbb{A}^{1}$ and for a punctured elliptic curve $E\setminus{0}$, and both at least produce quasi-unipotent answers. I´m confident that the computation for $E\setminus{0}$ generalises to hyperelliptic curves and so that´s a fairly broad class of *one dimensional* examples.

**Edit**, I am now fairly convinced that the monodromy is in fact finite in the one dimensional cases, and in fact in this case it's quite easy to prove directly by working formally locally at the singularities of the potential function $f$.

**Edit II** I believe the result is always true (that the monodromy is quasi-unipotent that is). Such should follow from the results of https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02802, in which it is shown that a quasi-unipotency result holds for Getzler's non commutative Gauss Manin connection on periodic cyclic homology of DG categories. One then applies this to the category of matrix factorizations $MF(X,f)$, which recovers the desired result.

Comment: I think that paper works with $\mathbb{Z}$-graded categories. The $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ case is not always a trivial adaptation, for example as far as I know Kaledin's work on degeneration doesn't apply there.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point! In this case the degen does hold, I think this was proven before Kaledin's theorem. In any case u're right, the paper cited is not necessarily sufficient to resolve the question, though I suspect it might do